# Is Visual Studio necessary for SQL database DevOps CI-CD pipeline?

Tags: sql-server, devops, database-project, cicd

I am new to DevOps and trying to create CI-CD pipeline for SQL database. In development environment, we use SSMS but when searching the tutorial for CI-CD, everyone is using Visual Studio to create a database project and then creating the CI-CD. Since Visual Studio is a licensed tool, do we need to have it? Is it the only option?

Comment: Visual Studio Community Edition is free and pretty sure SQL Database Products are included under its licence. ADS also has a SQL Server Databases Extension which is free. Which IDE you use is up to you; they all come with different benefits and nuances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Community Edition and install the SSDT (needed for database Projects).

See setup here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Changes%20in%20SSDT%20for%20Visual%20Studio%202019%20The,into%20the%20respective%20Visual%20Studio%20%28VSIX%29%20extensions%20only.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Changes%20in%20SSDT%20for%20Visual%20Studio%202019%20The,into%20the%20respective%20Visual%20Studio%20%28VSIX%29%20extensions%20only.)